# Launching Excel 2010 from VbScript with multiple versions of Excel installed

Tags: excel, batch-file, command-line, vbscript

I have a VbScript file which uses `CreateObject("Excel.Application")` to launch Excel then run a macro. This way, excel-based batches can be run without relying on Workbook_open methods.

The ideal solution, at least for a transitional period, would be to have some jobs running on Excel 2003 and others on 2010.

I've looked in the registry for a way to force a particular version, but this doesn't seem to be working. It wouldn't be ideal to be using the registry anyway, because two jobs could be running concurrently.

Is there a way to target a specific version in VbScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do this easily. The registry will associate "Excel.Application" with a particular excel.exe and changing that mid-session may cause problems.

You *could* try building your own COM object (you need to do that since you can't call DLL functions directly in VBScript) which will call regsvr on a particular version of excel. You will have to control that carefully: ensure you do this before creating an "Excel.Application" object. My hypothesis is that, after that, you're free to change the registry with a second call to regsvr via your COM object. Someone may have even written a COM-based regsvr already. And testing it would be trivial.

This approach *might* work: to my knowledge the CoClass GUIDs are only required by the COM factory. And subsequent queryInterface calls implicitly called by the VBScript runtime will rely on the interface UUIDs which will be consistent across the two versions. But my fear is that it would be too brittle to be useful in production.

The easiest thing to do, as I'm sure you know, would be to have two machines!

Comment: yes, the two machine approach was my initial suggestion :)

Comment: Not as fun as the other way though (which is probably a week of development time). Probably not economical.